# Why does Lint warns me about calling new methods on older versions when it's working on the older version?

Tags: android

In my code I have the following

```
PhoneNumberUtils.normalizeNumber(editUserInfosPhone.getText().toString())
```

But when I inspect the class, the Lint parts of the inspection tells me the following:

---

Call requires API level 21 (current min is 15): android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils#normalizeNumber

---

I have in my app's build.gradle the following :

```
defaultConfig {
        //package and code version parts skipped
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
```

But the codes that requires API level 21 works on a device with Jelly Bean API 16.
Why is it working on that device?

Comment: it's backward compatible

Comment: So do you mean that I can use all the new API in there previous versions thanks to the backward compatibility?